# Jitterbit support Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) as a valid source or destination?

Tags: msmq, jitterbit

Does Jitterbit support Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) as a valid source or destination?

I need to send a message to a queue have Jitterbit pick it up, process and send to another queue.

I would be interested in comments on the viability of this as an approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything on their website about MSMQ. 
Message queues seem to only be used internally by Jitterbit.
Looking at their wiki, Jitterbit can only accept data from, and send data to:

- FTP
- File Share
- Database
- HTTP

MSMQ does support sending messages over HTTP but not reading messages.
How about looking at using WCF+MSMQ?

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: Thanks John, it is as I suspected then. I was going the WCF route, but was hoping not to have to write code to do this, ho hum...